# How to edit sctp.h to add SO_REUSEADDR

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, sctp

I am running below two RPM packages for SCTP. 
lksctp-tools-1.0.11
lksctp-tools-devel-1.0.11

My header file for sctp is in /usr/include/netinet/sctp.h that has bind method but no listen method.

```
int sctp_bindx(int sd, struct sockaddr *addrs, int addrcnt, int flags);

int sctp_connectx(int sd, struct sockaddr *addrs, int addrcnt,
                  sctp_assoc_t *id);

int sctp_peeloff(int sd, sctp_assoc_t assoc_id);

/* Prototype for the library function sctp_opt_info defined in
 * API 7. Socket Options.
 */
int sctp_opt_info(int sd, sctp_assoc_t id, int opt, void *arg, socklen_t *size);
```

I want to use SO_REUSEADDR in this code to resolve 'Address already in use ' error in SCTP for kernel 2.6.32.

I learnt that below snippet can help in adding SO_REUSEADDR but I dont know where/how to add in the code:

```
int on = 1;
...
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof on);
bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof sin);
```

I am not educated in socket progamming but I am addressing the issue because on port 3868 a client request is made by a remote java process which throws 'Address already in Use' error as some other TCP process would be using the same port

Answer (score 0):

> I learnt that below snippet can help in adding `SO_REUSEADDR` but I dont know where/how to add in the code

You need to add the 2 lines:

```
int on = 1;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof on);
```

after you create the socket with `socket` call, but before `bind`.

Comment: I added the code in sctp.h file but I could not find if the socket call is in that file .I could find bind but not 'socket' call for socket creation.Is it possible that socket call must be created  in some other header file.I have multiple of files in /usr/include/netinet